# How can I reduce the time complexity from O(n^2) to O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I recently attended an interview and they asked me to solve the below problem by using `O(n)` time complexity. (Hackerranker)

**Problem:**

Given an integer array and there will be `l` integer and `r` integer. Need to find the which are all the pair of elements sum will be equal and in between `l` and `r` value;

> Example:
>
> ```
> int[] array = {2,3,4,5}; int l=5, int r=7;
> ```
>
> Output: 4

Input properties:

- The input is unsorted.
- The input will have duplicate elements.
- The input array is non-negative.

The below combination will return the sum which will be equal and in between `l` and `r` range value, where if the pair is less than `l` or greater than `r` it should be skipped. And pairs can't be duplicated:

```
array[0] + array[1] = 5 -> counter++
array[0] + array[2] = 6 -> counter++
array[0] + array[3] = 7 -> counter++
array[1] + array[2] = 7 -> counter++
array[1] + array[3] = 8 -> greater than r, no counter increment
```

I tried the below approach and it works fine but its time complexity is O(n^2):

```
 public static int sumPairs(int[] array,int l, int r)
    {
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
            {
                int sum = array[i]+array[j];
                
                if(sum<=r && sum>=l)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return counter;
    }
```

Can someone help me to find a way to optimize the above code to become `O(n)` time complexity?

Comment: Build a HashMap where the keys are the numbers, and the values are the number of occurrences of that number.

Comment: ryt said @AndyTurner same question as [TWO SUM](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) with a little twist

Comment: The best that I see is `O(n log(n))`.  The first step is to sort them.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `k` can very well be greater than `n`. All that matters is that it is a constant independent of `n`.

Comment: the HashMap described by @AndyTurner is also known as a frequency histogram

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Big O captures the worst case bound for *any* given `n`. So, the average value of `n` is immaterial when writing down an algorithm's Big O(n) function. You are talking about the average run time, which Big O does not care for.

Comment: @btilly radix sort is linear.

Comment: @Tryer You have fallen prey to misconception 4 in http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/big-o.html. Big-O is about mathematical functions.  They can be best case, average case, worst case, etc.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, with a number of passes proportional to the number of bits in the integer.  In a low-level language like C you can make this faster than comparison based sorts.  In a high-level language like Python, you can't.

Comment: @btilly btw I don't see why would it be impossible. Python has arrays with O(1) access; each number can be turned into an array of its digits in whatever *base*; then we sort by *k=0,1,...,d* -th digit. This assumes these ints are bounded from above (i.e. not bignums, but have finite range, up to *base^d* or so). we just needs a lot of space (length(array)*base), but the time complexity is still O(n).

Comment: @WillNess I'd need to see benchmarks for Java. As for Python, you can write the code, but the performance overhead of writing in Python is such you'll probably lose to the library `sort` until your arrays have too much data to fit in memory.  Try writing it and see.

Comment: @btilly yes but this is an *algorithmic* question. We only care about big-O, not the actual performance.

Comment: @WillNess You have to define "we" carefully. I am usually uninterested in algorithms that are worse for all datasets that we can manage to run for.

Comment: Since you can reduce element distinctness to this problem, proving a worst-case O(n) algorithm requires discussion about allowed models of computation or unmentioned constraints on the input. That doesn't preclude an O(n) randomized expected time complexity; you should specify what  'complexity' was sought.

Comment: @btilly Fair enough. *Usually* Big O notation *is* used to indicate worst case performance. My post was made under that assumption. If we are talking about the worst case performance, then it is indeed true that all that we care is how big n is and n alone is as long as k is a constant independent of n.

Comment: @Tryer Oh, really? Watch how many discussions talk about using a hash algorithm to achieve `O(1)` performance. In fact the worst case of common hashing implementations is `O(n)` and `O(1)` is the average case.

Comment: The question wants certain complexity, constant factors i.e. performance do not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach using a cumulative histogram instead of a sort. In c++, sorry.

```
static int sumPairsLinear(int *pArray,int iArraySize, int l, int r)
{
    int iResult = 0;
    // 1. Iterate the array and toss any entries larger than r
    for (int i=0;i<iArraySize;)
    {
        if (pArray[i] > r)
            pArray[i] = pArray[--iArraySize];
        else
            i++;
    }
    // 2. Allocate a zero initialised array of ints, of size `r+1`.
    int *pHistogram = new int[r+1];
    memset(pHistogram, 0, sizeof(int)*(r+1));
    // 3. Fill the histogram
    for (int i=0;i<iArraySize;i++)
    {
        pHistogram[pArray[i]]++;
    }
    // 4. Convert it to a cumulative histogram. 
    for (int i=1;i<=r;i++)
    {
        pHistogram[i] += pHistogram[i-1];
    }
    // 5. Iterate through the values again. Use the cumulative histogram to calculate the number of valid pairs.
    for (int i=0;i<iArraySize;i++)
    {
        int iVal = pArray[i];
        int iIndex = l-iVal-1;
        iResult += pHistogram[r-iVal] - ((iIndex >= 0) ? pHistogram[iIndex] : 0);
        // Don't pair with self
        iVal *= 2;
        if (iVal <= r &&
            iVal >= l)
        {
            iResult--;
        }
    }
    // 6. Half iResult because we counted each pair twice.
    iResult /= 2;

    delete[] pHistogram;
    return iResult;
}
```

Horrible performance if `r` is large but otherwise reasonable and still O(N).

Answer (score 2):

To find the number of pairs of elements in an array summing up to a value within given range, we will use radix sort, which applies in any case where we know in advance the maximum number of digits in any given number under consideration.

This trivially holds when the integer values are of some usual bounded `int` type, i.e. not bignums.

Otherwise, assuming all integers are positive, we first partition the array *in place* with the `r` value as the pivot, henceforth forgetting about the upper part of the array altogether.

Now,

1. Sort the array by [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) in *O(n)* in ascending order.
2. Scan the array from `i=0` with `j=1` incrementing `j` while `a[i]+a[j] < l`, next with `k=j` incrementing `k` until `a[i]+a[k] > r`. Decrement `k`. Set `count = k-j+1`.
3. Increment `i` once, possibly repeatedly decrementing `j` and `k` to maintain the boundary conditions, making sure `i =< j =< k`  and `i,j,k` are valid access.
4. If there are no valid `i,j,k`, go to 6. Otherwise,
5. Increment `count` by `k-j+1` and go back to 3.
6. Stop. `count` is the result.

(adjust the above for corner cases as needed.)

Comment: The assumption that the inputs are small enough to be radix-sorted in O(n) is key here. It may be necessary for an O(n) algorithm, but it should be explicitly stated when such an assumption is added to the problem.

Comment: `int`s are not bignums, in Java. their range is bounded. there is no "small enough", any bound will do. @kcsquared

Comment: Again, that comment is wrong. All that is needed for radix sort is to know in advance the maximum number of digits an integer can have, i.e. the range of the int data type.

Comment: @kcsquared I've amended the algorithm to also apply for *positive bignums* case.